# Does it matter if I use PHP or AJX to return formatted html containing data from my database?

Tags: php, jquery, database

I'm trying to fetch data from my database using PHP. Once I have this data, I want to format it into HTML .

There's two ways I know you can do this:

1. Create a function that creates a string of the formatted HTML and just return it. Eventually, you'll call the function and echo the returned string

   ```
    function getName() {
       //Do some data fetching here to get name...

       $string= "<p>".$name."</p>";
       return $string;
   }

   <div id="name">
      echo getName();
   </div>
   ```
2. Grab the data from a php file using AJAX and just format it there

   ```
   $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "getName.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var name = $('<p>').text(data['name']);
            $("#name").append(name);           
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
   ```

My question is does it matter which way I do this?

Comment: IMHO an API should return data and the front end should present it.  This decouples the presentation from the retrieval of information.  But as this is opinion based, I have voted to close.

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you for the response. Yea I thought this might be the case, just wondering what others' opinions were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically your example is a matter of personal preference. Just be consistent at all levels.

However, it is usually best practice to do formatting on the client-side. Let the server handle data operations, and the browser handle rendering the data. It does depend on your full stack though.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. Thank you!